# Magento2 How to add custom validation for password?

Tags: magento2, form-validation, password

I want to change default validation for all password field.

I want to change for all password field and validation is minimum 8 characters and at least one number include.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you want to allow only digit to password field then you want to go with custom JS validation.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Do i need to override default JS for validation?

Comment: No you don't need to override JS file you need to override phtml file and add custom script to phtml file.

Check my answer.

Comment: Can you please let me know which phtml file do i need to override? And what exactly comes in custom script?

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Have you got solution or need some clarification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@chirag, Thanks for your suggestion and from your suggestion i have made changes in register.phtml file and now my requirement is working. Please check below my code.

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

I have added below script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'jquery/validate',
    'mage/translate'
], function($){
    $.validator.addMethod(
    'validate-mycustom-password', function (value) {
    return (value.length >= 8 && /^(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/.test(value));
    }, $.mage.__('Minimum 8 characters with at least one number'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to validate customer login password then override phtml file in to your design folder like below.

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/login.phtml

Find the line `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-password':true}"`

And replace with `data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-mycustom-password':true}"`

Add the following code at the end of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate'
        ], function($){
            $.validator.addMethod(
                'validate-mycustom-password', function (value) { 
                    return (value.length == 6 && /^-?\d+$/.test(value));
                }, $.mage.__('Password length should be 6 and only numbers are allowed'));
        });
</script>
```

Don't forgot to run necessary command like `static:content:deploy` & `cache:flush`

**Note:** I give a validation for Max limit & allow only number. you have to customize script as per your requirement.

Comment: hi, @Chirag how can we add validation for custom fields, i have a new form like create account, how can we add same validation there

Answer (score 1):

This is a configuration item.

> In Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration >
>   Password Options

There is an option for **Number of Required Character Classes**:

[image]

Comment: i got this option but i want to display validation like below.

"minimum 8 characters with at least one number"

Comment: Go to adminpanel - stores - configuration - customers - customers configuration - Number of Required Character Classes and set 3.

Comment: and set Min length 8, it will match your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is available in configuration item in the **Admin Panel**

In **Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password Options** there are options like **Minimum Password Length** and **Number of Required Character Classes**

Comment: i have checked what did you mentioned but minimum character is set to 8 but in Number of Required Character Classes how to set only Digits?